# What is the literary device that describes phrases like "faithfully unfaithful"?

Tags: rhetorical-devices, oxymoron

I came across a Wikipedia page a few months ago that described a literary device that had two opposite words side by side in a sentence.

Unlike an oxymoron ("horribly kind", "run slow"), this page described words that were almost identical, but one word was the "un" of the other word. For example:

- She was faithfully unfaithful to him

It is still a type of oxymoron, but I know the word I was thinking of to describe them that I read on the Wiki page was different.

Note: I'm not thinking of a tautology either. In the sentence above, "faithfully" adds more context to the unfaithful - she was faithful to her unfaithfulness.

Comment: You mean like [an unwelcome welcome?](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22an+unwelcome+welcome%22) I'd just say such usages are ***puns / wordplay***.

Comment: 'Contradictory'

Comment: How about paradox (in the rhetorical sense)?

Comment: "_Oxymoron_" hits the spot, as it does for "_frameless frames_" (either of the picture-hanging variety or of spectacles).  I don't know of anything more specific.  BTW, _tautology_ is very much the opposite of oxymoron!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A loud silence has ensued](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65674/a-loud-silence-has-ensued)

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for **juxtaposition**:

> The fact of two things being seen or placed close together with contrasting effect.

Source: [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/juxtaposition)

> The act or an instance of placing two or more things side by side often to compare or contrast or to create an interesting effect

Source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/juxtaposition)

> The juxtaposition of two contrasting objects, images, or ideas is the fact that they are placed together or described together, so that the differences between them are emphasized.

Source: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/juxtaposition)

Answer (score 1):

**Oxymoron**, a figure of speech / literary device  for such combinations: *thunderous silence*, *sweet sorrow* , *deafening silence* e.t.c

Please check [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/oxymoron)

> **Oxymoron**:If you describe a phrase as an oxymoron, you mean
>   that what it refers to combines two opposite qualities or ideas and
>   therefore seems impossible.